# Does a suffix need to be an affix?

Tags: meaning, grammar, terminology, ambiguity, semantics

I understand that according to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/suffix#:%7E:text=an%20affix%20that%20follows%20the%20stem%20to%20which%20it%20is%20attached%2C%20as%20for%20example%20%2Ds%20and%20%2Dness%20in%20dogs%20and%20softness:%7E:text=an%20affix%20that%20follows%20the%20stem%20to%20which%20it%20is%20attached%2C%20as%20for%20example%20%2Ds%20and%20%2Dness%20in%20dogs%20and%20softness), a suffix is an affix that follows the stem to which it is attached, as for example -s and -ness in dogs and softness. It has, however, a second definition:

> anything that is added at the end of something else.

Would I then be right if I say that the following sentences have the same suffix " is a vehicle."?

1. An airplane is a vehicle.
2. A car is a vehicle.

Comment: You'd confuse people who expected you to be using "suffix" in the normal way it's used when talking about grammar and sentences. You could search and see how "suffix" is used in different texts, but I think you'd very seldom find it used in the way you want to use it. Of course you could tell your readers that you are using "suffix" in a special, non-standard way. If you want to know the actual grammatical term for "is a vehicle", I'm sure someone here can tell you.

Comment: So technically it is not wrong, but I should not use it like that. Got it, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is technically wrong to invent new uses of a word outside of poetry and lyrics. You will confuse readers if you announce that "sprinkle black pepper over the dish" at the end of a recipe is a suffix, since you add it *at the end of something else* (the recipe).

Comment: It's wrong. It violates the Gricean maxim of manner, if that's technical enough a reason. It's certainly wrong enough to mislead, confuse, and lose marks in academic work.

Comment: Note that the second definition you refer to is only in the British English section of that dictionary. So Americans won't understand this use.

Comment: And in the context of words, I think even Brits would assume that the first definition is intended. So you shouldn't use "suffix" for this.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming, BTW?

Comment: No! You misread the entry in Collins Dictionary. The second definition you refer to is not about grammar, whereas the first specifically says _grammar_.

Comment: @Barmar American English also has a second definition of suffix: "anything added to the end of something else"

Comment: @Barmar It is normal in programming to make a variable of string of ending of multiple sentences. For example var msgSuffix = "is a vehicle". You can then just use this to make other string variables (var car = "car " + msgSuffix; var plane = "plane " + msgSuffix). Not the best example but you get the idea. This problem struck me when I was trying to give a name to this variable.

Comment: @Barmar It's also in [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/suffix), so 'Americans won't understand this use' is over-restrictive. Though I'd say it's a rare usage even in the UK.

Comment: Btw, any idea why I got 2 downvotes? Not complaining, only curious.

Comment: @NicolasOthmar: I suspect the downvoters thought the question misguided or too simple. Sometimes, too, some folks don't take newbie seriously. This site is often far from perfect. Hermanen, though, has provided an excellent response. And take heart in the fact that so far no one has voted to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In grammar, yes, a *suffix* is an affix just like a prefix and an infix. [*Wiktionary*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/suffix)    lists two other senses of the word *suffix* used in mathematics and computing along with the primary sense in grammar:

> 1. *(grammar, linguistic morphology)* A morpheme added at the end of a word to modify the word's meaning. 
>    Synonym: *(narrow sense)* affix 
>    Antonym: prefix 
>    The suffix "-able" changes "sing" into "singable".
> 2. *(mathematics)* A subscript.
> 3. *(computing)* A final segment of a string of characters. 
>    The string "abra" is both a prefix and a suffix of the string "abracadabra".

I have no idea why [*Collins Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/suffix) lists the second sense "something added to the end of something else" for the word *suffix* which is too general and ambiguous. This sense is not listed in reputable dictionaries like *OED* where only the senses in grammar and mathematics are listed. I would disregard this sense of *suffix* listed in Collins.

---

Update:

I've taken the liberty to contact Collins Dictionary and asked them why they've listed this sense of the word "suffix". They've said that it is a figurative sense of it. Here is the full reply:

> As you are aware, this word is almost always used in the context of grammar. However, it is occasionally used in a figurative sense to describe anything that is added to something else in the same way that a suffix is added to the end of a word to modify its meaning.
>
> The following examples show this figurative use of the word:
>
> *When she suggested I should go to therapy, there was the implied suffix "and do the work the therapist asks".*
>
> *They should have added some suffix to the film's name to differentiate it from the first film.*
>
> In neither case is the speaker using 'suffix' in a literal way to mean a group of letters at the end of the word. Instead, they are using 'suffix' figuratively to refer to something that is added to something that is not a word (an additional request in the first case; a subtitle in the second).
>
> You can also use 'suffix' figuratively as a verb:
>
> *The letter was suffixed by a request for money.*